# Find value with different conditions

Tags: excel

I am trying to sum the bonus for specific activities my employees do. I have a table with the standard bonus values for each bonus(and also for each level of employee), similar like this:

| Position | Bonus name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Operator level C | Bonus A | $5 |
| Operator level C | Bonus B | $7 |
| Operator level B | Bonus A | $4 |
| Operator level A | Bonus A | $7 |
| HR level C | Bonus A | $7.50 |
| HR level A | Bonus B | $6.50 |
| HR level A | Bonus C | $6.50 |

Then I have another table with which activities my employees performed during the week (where "1" represents that he/she done it and "0" activities not done:

| Employee ID | Position | Bonus name | Performed or not |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Operator level C | Bonus A | 1 |
| 1234 | Operator level C | Bonus A | 0 |
| 1220 | HR level A | Bonus B | 1 |
| 1220 | HR level A | Bonus C | 1 |
| 1278 | Operator level B | Bonus A | 1 |

My final desired output is going to be:

| Employee ID | Amount (all bonus calculation) |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | $5 |
| 1220 | $13 |
| 1278 | $4 |

I also have another table with the employee name, ID and level (like ex: Operator level C).

That is it guys, hopefully you can help me finding an easy way to get this final desired output.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of excel are you on? 365?

Comment: Hi Mark, yes!!!!

Answer (score 0):

First I'm assuming your first table spans from A1:C8, so I'm writing this all with that in mind, but naming these tables will likely save you trouble in the future as the formulas will adjust with the table. You can do this using `CTRL` + `T`

In the second table you have shown, I would make an additional column that uses an `Index` + `Match` formula.

Depending on your version of excel this might be an array and needs to be closed by hitting `CTRL` + `Shift` + `Enter` (365 can ignore this note)

`=INDEX($A$1:$C$8,MATCH(1,($A$1:$A$8=[Position Cell])*($B$1:$B$8=[Bonus Name Cell]),0),3)*[Performed Cell]`

For Bonus Name Cell, Position Cell, and Performed Cell simply reference that row's respective column.

Now the final steps. Highlighting this table, under `Insert` in the ribbon insert `PivotTable`.

Then drag the EmployeeID into the bottom left box, and the whatever you named this new column into the bottom right to get the values. Format as necessary.